# Host wildcard subdomains using postfix

Tags: postfix

I'm trying to work out how I can get postfix to accept email for any sub-domain of my main site.  I don't have virtual domains, just a long list of sub-domains for local delivery.  In specific, I'm feeding `python@*.mydomain.com` into a Python using the alias file:

```
python:    |/www/proc_email.py
```

The Python can handle delivery from there.  I envision this looking something along the lines of:

```
mydestination = encendio, localhost.localdomain, localhost, *.mydomain.com
```

I'm running the latest version of postfix on Ubuntu (not rightly sure how to check the version).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't use wildcards if you explicitly list the destinations in your Postfix config, but fortunately the `$mydestination` option accepts table lookups.  So try setting `$mydestination` to a [pcre map](http://www.postfix.org/pcre_table.5.html) like this:

```
mydestination = pcre:/etc/postfix/mydestinations
```

Then create `/etc/postfix/mydestinations` with properly anchored and escaped regexps:

```
/^encendio$/                  ACCEPT
/^localhost\.localdomain$/    ACCEPT
/^localhost$/                 ACCEPT
/^.*\.mydomain\.example$/     ACCEPT
```

Technically you could put anything at all in the place of "ACCEPT" as the result is ignored; just the [presence of the match is sufficient](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination):

> Specify a list of host or domain names,  "/file/name"  or  "type:table"
>   patterns, separated by commas and/or whitespace. A "/file/name" pattern
>   is replaced by its contents; a "type:table"  lookup  table  is  matched
>   when  a name matches a lookup key (the lookup result is ignored).

Comment: The regular expressions should be achored; see http://serverfault.com/a/352928/84843

Answer (score 20):

The pcre solution in the accepted answer works well, but you might want to consider anchoring the regexp to avoid getting hits on just part of the domain name.

```
/^encendio$/                  ACCEPT
/^localhost\.localdomain$/    ACCEPT
/^localhost$/                 ACCEPT
/^.*\.mydomain\.com$/         ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

`*.mydomain.com` wont work.

You need to create `relay-domains` and put all your subdomains in there. 1 per line.